# DynamoDB Best practice to select all items from a table with pagination (Without PK)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I simply want to get a list of products back from my table and paginated, the pagination part is relatively clear with `last_evaluated_key`, however all the examples are using on PK or SK, but in my case I just want to get paginated results sort by createdAt.

My product id (uniq uuid) is not very useful in this case. Is the last solution to scan the whole table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will use `Scan`.  DynamoDB has two types of read operation, `Query` and `Scan`.  You can `Query` for one-and-only-one `Partition Key` (and optionally a [range of](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) `Sort Key` values if your table has a [compound primary key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)).  Everything else is a `Scan`.

[Scan operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) read *every* item, max 1 MB, optionally filtered.  Filters are applied after the read.  Results are unsorted.

The SDKs have pagination helpers like [paginateScan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/globals.html#paginatescan) to make life easier.

Re: Cost.  Ask yourself:  *"is `Scan` returning lots of data MB I don't actually need?"*  If the answer is *"No"*, you are fine.  The more you are overfetching, however, the greater the cost benefit of `Query` over `Scan`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, many documentation and examples mentions the high cost of `Scan` operation when the table grow big. Will the `Scan` query scale with proper patination in place?

Comment: Yes, of course - `Scan` does exactly the same paging as `Query` does. Its high cost stems from the fact that you'll be reading your entire database and paying proportional to that entire size. To perform the huge scan faster (but not cheaper!), it is also possible to do a parallel scan - with different clients scanning a different part of the whole data - see "Segment" in the documentation.

Comment: @user1883793 `Scan` operations are problematic if they _overfetch MB_.  If your `Scan` is returning the data you need and not much more, then you are fine.  Use the [DynamoDB cost calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/DynamoDB) to estimate costs for your use case.  Performance scaling is a key feature of DynamoDB.  Cost scaling is influenced by table design and configuration.